# Нет перевода итогов выборов 2017

Tags: дефект, локализация, выборы

Ну что ж, вот и ещё "выборные" строки ждут перевода:

> 4,242 voters were eligible, 1,949 visited the site during the
>   election, 1,575 visited the election page, and 788 voted

На [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/):

> [image: Выборы модераторов]

Раньше только Nofate их озвучивал в чате, доступны из-под модераторских логинов -- а теперь публично видны. Переводим? )

И ещё мне непонятно почему результаты прошлых выборов уже русифицированы, а эти нет? Другой шаблон, по одному каждые выборы? Если так, то перевод корявый -- "1900 голосовали пользователи", не по-русски.

И на [этой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2) итоги не переведены:

> [image: Важные ссылки]

А именно фраза "The results of this election can be viewed online via OpaVote."

Comment: Не только эта фраза, но и те, что под картинками выбранных модераторов.

Comment: @edem это одна и та же фраза.

Comment: Я добавил пару переводов из 81. Как раз для случаев, покрывающих два упомянутых. Посмотрим, изменится ли что-то. Ждём сборки `> 2017.10.26.27573`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Текст о выборах 2015 года, т.е.:

> 1,946 голосовали пользователи, имевшие на это право, во время голосования сайт посетили 639 пользователей, 671 пользователей посетили страницу голосования, и 320 проголосовало

судя по всему уже где-то захадкожен. Т.е. такого перевода нет в Transifex, а значит, чтобы его исправить (а это хорошо бы сделать из-за некоторой кривизны имеющейся формулировки) нужно привлекать как минимум сотрудника (не уверен, что обычный избранный ромб сможет тут помочь).

[Шаблонная строка](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/108334463?key=36604f58571398c045eaa41285efad68) вида:

> $EligibleVoters$ voters were eligible, $VisitedSiteDuringElection$ visited the site during the election, $ViewedElection$ visited the election page, and $Voted$ voted

есть в Transifex, но на текущий момент не содержит перевода и перевод её затруднителен из-за одновременного присутствия в строке 4 переменных, которые дают 81 вариант перевода. Более подробно о [проблеме](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911) можно почитать на MSE и при желании плюсануть описанное [предложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Хочется верить, что всё же есть какое-то критическое количество голосов, после которого разработчики начинают прислушиваться ко мнению сообщества.

В принципе, по прошествии выборов все числовые значения уже зафиксированы и можно было бы перевести всего лишь не более N строк, где N - количество выборов. Но здесь вступает в силу проблема, описанная в самом начале, что строка не подлежит автоматическому изменению после окончания выборов, даже если поправить перевод в Transifex. Может быть проблему удастся решить, дёрнув какой-то дополнительный триггер в виде неведомого скрипта, как это было с ситуацией про [общие удалённые вопросы](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35731835#35731835). Но понять это без участия разработчиков не получится.

Перевод для [фразы](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/110994310?key=5953d3346576b3b7e39c49569f217f9c):

> The results of this election can be viewed online via OpaVote.

добавил такой:

> Результаты выборов можно посмотреть онлайн через OpaVote.

Если этот текст живёт нормальной жизнью большинства других строк на сайте, а не так как описанных в самом начале этого текста, то перевод будет на сайте после подгрузки базы и пересборки движка.

Comment: Обрати внимание на этот вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6231/178988 - там немного другой список замечаний.

Comment: @Qwertiy про п.1 подробно рассказано здесь, остальные пункты явно зависят от перевода, который я не готов делать 81 раз к ряду.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ перевёл строки. Перевод не появился. Видимо, захардкожено на английском.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica неужели выборы грядут в эпоху пандемии?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ с чего вдруг? )

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica просто неожиданный коммент к сообщению про выборы )

Comment: @αλεχολυτ просто слова добавил, хотел уже закрыть вопрос. Оказывается, у них всё как обычно)

Comment: Надеюсь этот вопрос получит второе дыхание :)