# Не локализованы результаты выборов

Tags: дефект, локализация

Это сообщение нужно перевести

> 4,242 voters were eligible, 1,949 visited the site during the election, 1,575 visited the election page, and 788 voted

1. Причём странно, что для первых выборов по-русски, а для вторых - нет.
2. пробел после числа должен быть неразрывным - 639 в конце строки не смотрится.
3. "голосовали пользователи, имевшие на это право" != "voters were eligible".
   Надо переводить как "могло проголосовать".

[image: скриншот]

Comment: @AK, ой.. Не заметил... Но у меня 3 пункта, а у тебя только один из них и ещё один другой, так что не дубликатится никуда :)

Comment: Я вас выбирал, чтобы самому не думать )) Решите сами, что делать.

Comment: @AK, оставить 2 вопроса :)

Comment: Непривычно ромб у Вас видеть :)

Comment: ой, кажется, я закрывашка ._.

Comment: @mymedia ещё и вопрос модератора ... могут и отшлёпать!