# Кнопка править список дубликатов ведёт на 404

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дубликаты

Вижу кнопку для правки списка дубликатов, которая ведёт на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/originals/6231/edit, но там 404.

[image: скриншот]

metaSE: [Duplicate list "edit" link erroneously displayed on non-closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296466/309650)

Comment: Кажется кому-то подсунули бракованный ромб...

Comment: It looks like that page will 404 if the question isn't marked as duplicate, and [it isn't](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6231/Не-локализованы-результаты-выборов), so maybe it was reopened while you were looking at it.  I don't see that post having ever been closed though, so I'm not sure what made the message appear.

Comment: @BrianNickel, it has never been closed. And it's not closed now. But if I open it now, I see the button like on the screenshot. And it leads to 404.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ah, I see.  I didn't realize that screen appeared in some cases for open questions.  I found another description of the problem [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296466/duplicate-list-edit-link-erroneously-displayed-on-non-closed-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправлено со следующего билда.

В коде предполагалось, что если плашка показывается, то вопрос закрыт. Небольшая дополнительная проверка скроет кнопку.

---

This will be fixed in the next build.

The code assumed that if the dialog was visible, the question was closed.  A simple additional check hides the button.