# Доработка перевода страницы выборов

Tags: предложение, локализация, выборы

На [странице выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election) формулировка результатов первых выборов похожа на машинный перевод, результаты вторых выборов не переведены.

> [image: Таблица выборов]

Предлагаю следующий перевод:

> N1 пользовател(ь,я,ей) имели право голоса, из них N2 посещали сайт во время выборов, N3 посетили страницу голосования, N4 проголосовали.

Comment: Только варианты перевода лучше постить в ответы, чтобы за них можно было голосавать независимо от вопроса - вдруг у кого-то ещё идеи появятся.

Comment: Утверждение "из них" про число посетивших страницу выборов неверно. Кажется.

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле, я [вчера добавил перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6224/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-2017?rq=1#comment24211_6224) для пары вариантов, которые должны были бы покрывать прошедшие выборы, но там есть [свои приколы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6232/176217), из-за которых перевод фактически не применяется.

Был добавлен [такой вариант](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/108334476?key=36604f58571398c045eaa41285efad68%7CEligibleVotersCount%3Dfew%2CViewedElectionCount%3Dmany%2CVisitedSiteDuringElectionCount%3Dmany%2CVotedCount%3Dmany):

> $EligibleVoters$ могло проголосовать, $VisitedSiteDuringElection$ посетили сайт во время выборов, $ViewedElection$ посетили страницу выборов, из них $Voted$ проголосовали

Повторюсь, перевод сейчас не работает по независящим от переводчика причинам. Надо <s>пинать</s> уговаривать Николаса <s>пинать</s> просить разработчиков выяснить в чём дело.